# Scrollview and child with flex: 1

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

Is it possible to have a layout which is wrapped with `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView>
  <View>dynamic height</View>
  <View>flex with minHeight</View>
  <View>static height</View>
</ScrollView>
```

and meets below prerequisites:

Height of the first `View` is dynamic (depends on text length). Height of the third `View` is static (always three buttons inside). Rest of the screen should be filled with `View` with map, but the minimal height is set to 250.

Now the tricky part: if there is a lot of text in first `View`, so that map doesn't fit, a scroll should appear. I couldn't achieve that. I was trying to give the map `View` `flex: 1` and `minHeight: 250`, but it's not rendered at all.

### Solution

Ok, I've found a way to fix it. In first render, I get screen height (`Dimensions`) and height of first and third view (`onLayout`). Then, I calculate the height of second view (`screenHeight - view1 - view3 - naviagtionHeight`) and `forceUpdate()` to re-render it.

[image]

Answer (score 27):

Add `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}` prop to `ScrollView` and its children's `flex:1` would work. So you don't need to calculate it manually.